# Place comment after while statement in algorithmic

Tags: formatting, comments, algorithmic

I am having some trouble placing plain text in my algorithm using the `algorithmic` package. The problem only seems to occur after a '\WHILE' command. I need to start my 'while' loop, then immediately place a piece of text with a brief description of the next sub-section of code.

I currently insert text in the code as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\STATE line 1
\STATE line 2
\WHILE {test}

\STATE line 4

\textit {describe the next step 2}
\STATE line 5
\ENDWHILE
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

Which produce the type of text I want within the code, i.e. a piece of text with no algorithm line number associated with it.

So, based on that, what I think should work is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\STATE line 1
\STATE line 2
\WHILE {test}

\textit {describe the next step 1}

\STATE line 4

\textit {describe the next step 2}
\STATE line 5
\ENDWHILE
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

However, this produces errors:

```
line 12: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \STATE

line 12: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \STATE

..snip..

line 16: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \ENDWHILE
```

and nonsense formatting on the output.

The nearest I can get is to insert an additional line (which I do not want) as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\STATE line 1
\STATE line 2
\WHILE {test}
\STATE Inserted Text

\textit {describe the next step 1}

\STATE line 4

\textit {describe the next step 2}
\STATE line 5
\ENDWHILE
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

or use the `\STATE` command on the line with the text, which gives the text a line number.

Any ideas what's going on and, of course, what the cure is?

After the answer from Werner (thanks) I thought this might help clarify it a bit better. The pseudo-code is heavily mathematical so not immediately clear what's happening. So I want to place a one line comment 'describe lines 4-6' this may be clearer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\STATE line 1
\STATE line 2
\WHILE {test}

\STATE line 4
\STATE line 5
\STATE line 6

\textit {describe lines 7-9}
\STATE line 7
\STATE line 8
\STATE line 9

\textit {describe lines 10-12}
\STATE line 10
\STATE line 11
\STATE line 12
\ENDWHILE
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Added clearer code at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under [`algorithmic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) you can add a *comment* on the same line as your `\WHILE` using an optional argument:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithmic}

%\newcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\{#1\}}% Original definition
\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\textit{#1}}% Updated definition

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \STATE line 1
  \STATE line 2
  \WHILE [describe while condition] {test}
    \STATE line 4
    \textit {describe the next step 2}
    \STATE line 5
  \ENDWHILE
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

Note that the default formatting for comments is via `\algorithmiccomment{<comment>}` which sets `{<comment>}` - a comment inside a pair of curly braces `{`...`}`. Above I've reformatted that to `\textit{<comment>}`.

---

The following minimal example builds on what has already been suggested above by providing a starred version of `\STATE*`. The starred version doesn't print any line number:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithmic,xpatch}

%\newcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\{#1\}}% Original definition
\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\textit{#1}}% Updated definition

\makeatletter

\xpatchcmd{\algorithmic}% <cmd>
  {\newcommand{\STATE}{\ALC@it}}% <search>
  {\newcommand{\STATE}{\@ifstar\STATEstar\STATEnostar}}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\newcommand{\STATEstar}{\item[]}
\newcommand{\STATEnostar}{\ALC@it}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \STATE line 1
  \STATE line 2
  \WHILE [describe while condition] {test} \label{first}
    \STATE* \textit {describe the item on line~\ref{first}}
    \STATE line 4 \label{second}
    \textit {describe step~\ref{second}}
    \STATE line 5
  \ENDWHILE
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I had tried the 'comment' option and the it doesn't produce what I want. As you have described, the comment refers to a description of the 'while' and so is appropriate to be on the same line. However, i wish the comment to be on a new line, as shown in the first example 'describe the next step'.
The comment refers to the next block of the pseudo-code, not the 'while' command. Because it refers to a block of code, placing the comment on the same line is confusing.

Comment: @Rich: See my updated answer. I now provide `\STATE*`.

Comment: Excellent, thanks!
I found a clue in there as well that achieves it without defining the new command, just add '\item[]' in front ofthe textit{}

Comment: @Rich: That's exactly what `\STATE*` does. It's just better to keep a common syntax. The patch of the `algorithmic` environment is necessary, as [`algorithmic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) makes all its definitions as part of the `algorithmic` environment start. So they're only defined when you type `\begin{algorithmic}`...